# Adding value to start of string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am working with price lists, and am trying to add a £ to the start of my values. This is being required from an Oracle 11g database.

```
to_char('£' + (case when web_cost.cost is null then 0 else 
round(web_cost.cost,2) end)) as unitcost
```

web_cost.cost should produce values in the following format; 11.50, or 0 or null values possibly.

The above query is giving me invalid number error, I have even tried to_char on every section of this code, and have still had no luck.

This is the only section of my query that currently does not work, any ideas?

Comment: The "+" is the problem. May be this comes from a java code, but in Oracle Pl/SQL the concatenation is done using `||`. Also, hardcoding '£' is not a good practice - try to get it dynamically (from another table or somewhere else), as when you run this code for a client using a different currency, you will hardcode it again etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR` with the format model `L` to show the currency. If your default currency is not `£` then you can supply the 3rd argument to set the `NLS_CURRENCY`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55bef/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE web_cost ( cost ) AS
SELECT 1234.567   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98765      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 34567.8901 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL       FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         COALESCE( cost, 0 ),
         'FML999990D00',
         'NLS_CURRENCY=£'
       ) AS unitcost
FROM   web_cost
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55bef/2/0)**:

```
|  UNITCOST |
|-----------|
|  £1234.57 |
| £98765.00 |
| £34567.89 |
|     £0.00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use concat  `||` for join the string

```
select '£' || to_char(case when web_cost.cost is null then 0 else 
      round(web_cost.cost,2) end)) as unitcost
```